# How do you say "grounding", as in a grounding aroma?

Tags: single-word-requests

In books on aromatherapy, DIY soapmaking, etc., you will find some fragrances described as "grounding". This basically means bringing a feeling of stability, calm, and connectedness to life. I was reading an aromatherapy book, and as I've gotten into a habit of mentally translating things I read into Esperanto, I realized I didn't have any idea how to say "grounding", and I can't find it in ReVo. How does one express this concept in Esperanto?

Comment: Not knowing anything about aroma therapy, I decided not to attempt an answer to this one. What I would be interested to know from the people answering is how does the term in Esperanto compare to the term in other national languages. Does "grounding aroma" even exist as an international concept? (I don't know either way.)

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting one, especially as the English phrase *grounding aroma* is itself not self-explanatory.

> Being grounded can refer to being physically, emotionally, mentally, energetically and/or spiritually rooted. This doesn’t mean rigid or unchanging [...] People who are grounded are fully present, in the moment, alert and aware of their physical existence and boundaries. They have clarity and conviction and can “hold their ground:” they don’t tend to waver or oscillate with each new interaction that they have. [<sup>1</sup>](http://www.starchaser-healingarts.com/aromatherapy-essential-oils-for-grounding/)

Tony's answer was *stabiliga aromo*, which is likely to be the best choice in context.

Because the word is connected to *stabilizing* in chemistry etc, to clarify it you could say *stabilsentiga*.

Other possibilities are *(re)enradikiga* ("rerooting"), *(re)centranta* ("recentering"), *alhejmiga* ("homebringing").

Answer (score 3):

The other answers given focus on the nuance of stabilising but if you wish to emphasise the calming nature then you could use the word *trankviliga*.

Answer (score 2):

- Stabilizing feeling = Stabiliga sento
- Stable feeling = Stabila sento